# how to get employee name using corresponding id from lookup table using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a sql query as following:

`table1` has:

```
 name1, name2, date .....
```

`user_table` has:

```
employee_id, employee_name
```

`table1` has `id` values under column `name1` and `name2` and `user_table` has `id` and corresponding name.

It would have been a straight forward join. But after the date `2019-03-20`, `name1` and `name2` from `table1` have `id` like `100101`, `100102`. And before `2019-03-20`, `name1` and `name2` has values such as `tom`, `dick`, `harry` etc.

The goal here is obvious, to replace the `id` values with employee names in `table1`

My initial idea is to do a `UNION` between two segments of the `table1`, before `2019-03-20` and after `2019-03-20`.

```
select t.*, u.employee_name as name1a, u1.employee_name as name2a 
from table1 t
  left join user_table u on t.name1= u.employee_id
  left join user_table u1 on t.name2 = u1.employee_id
where
  cast(t.approvedate as date) > '2019-03-20';
```

**question 1**: Is there a better solution than doing UNION?

**question 2**: To do a UNION both sides must have the same number of columns. But the query above will produce two additional columns `name1a`, `name2a`. Now I can just select the column names to avoid that issue, but what if I have too many columns to list in the select statement ?

---

> Updated with sample table and desired result. I have following tables:

test_sales

```
CREATE TABLE test_sales (product varchar(20) ,sales_date varchar(20), person_1 varchar(20) , person_2 varchar(20) ) ;

INSERT INTO test_sales (product, sales_date, person_1, person_2) VALUES ('abc', '2019-04-01', '101', '110'), ('abc', '2019-04-10', '102', '111'),('abc', '2019-03-15', 'tom', 'john'), ('xyz', '2019-03-21', 'tom', 'dick'), ('xyz', '2019-03-29', 'harry', 'josh'), ('xyz', '2019-04-05', '102', '110'), ('xyz', '2019-03-29', 'harry', 'josh'), ('pqr', '2019-04-02', '101', '111');
```

[image]

test_user

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE test_user (employee_id varchar(10) ,employee_name varchar(20));

INSERT INTO test_user (employee_id, employee_name) VALUES ('101', 'john'),('102', 'josh'), ('110', 'tom'), ('111', 'dick');
```

And I want to get following output where the blank cells will also have names.

[image]

Right now I have this query which produces the result with blank cells.

```
select s.product, s.sales_date, u.employee_name as person_1, u1.employee_name as person_2 from test_sales s left join test_user u on s.person_1 = u.employee_id left join test_user u1 on s.person_2 =u1.employee_id;
```

Comment: "tom, dick, harry etc" aren't IDs in the table `users`?

Comment: no. these mixed values are only in table1 for . user_table has id such as 100101, 100102 and corresponding name such as tom, dick etc.

Comment: Then your real goal should be to fix this and only use IDs.

Comment: well that cant be done at the moment.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help

Comment: Updated the question with sample data.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code & desired output & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving relation(ship)s/associations or tables say exactly what a row says about the business situation in terms of its column values when it is in the table. Also when describing a query result. PS  Please don't append updates, just make your post the best presentation as of right now.

Comment: would it be better to post a new question ?

Answer (score 0):

You could join using an OR operator:

```
 select t.*, u.employee_name as name1a, u1.employee_name as name2a 
 from table1 t
    left join user_table u 
       on t.name1= u.employee_id
          OR t.name2 = u.employee_id
          OR t.name1 = u.employee_name
          OR t.name2 = u.employee_name
```

It's not going to be fast, but it may do the trick. Optionally you can do 4 joins (`name1` and `name2` for `id`, and then `name1` and `name2` for name) and use coalesce:

```
 select t.*, COALESCE(u.employee_name, u2.employee_name, u3.employee_name, u4.employee_name) AS employee_name
 from table1 t
    left join user_table u 
       on t.name1= u.employee_id
    left join user_table u2 
       ON t.name2 = u2.employee_id
    left join user_table u3 
       ON t.name1 = u3.employee_name
    left join user_table u4 
       ON t.name2 = u4.employee_name
```

Comment: For the first solution u1.employee_name as name2a ... do you mean u ? instead of u1 ? if you do, this is producing same name for both name1a and name2a. If you actually meant u1 then there is no alias for u1 in your code.

Comment: Sorry. That whole column in the select should be removed. Just a single employee_name column in the output

Comment: I have updated the question with sample data. Both name columns are required, combining them in a single column wont make sense.